# Repleace relationship by name of this relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a model User with fileds like - colorhair_id, nationality_id, etc. Of course I have a relationship to other model. Problem is that I want to return nationality from User i must do that:

```
User::find(1)->colorhair->name
```

In next time I need to use

```
User::find(1)->nationality->name
```

It works but it's not look professional and it's dirty. How can I change query or something else to return object with repleace field like nationality_id to nationality with name of that. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you don't need a relation there. If models are simple enough just store needed info in the same table. In your specific case I'd make just a profile model with all those info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel **Mutators**. Put below two functions into the User model

```
public function getHairColorNameAttribute(){
        return $this->colorhair->name
}

public function getNationalityNameAttribute(){
    return $this->nationality->name
}
```

Then when you simply access it.

```
User::find(1)->hair_color_name;
```

The next time

```
User::find(1)->nationality_name;
```

If you want to get these values by default use $append in the model. Put the following line to the top of the User model

```
protected $appends = ['hair_color_name','nationality_name'];
```

*Note: In laravel 9 mutators little bit different from the above method.*

Bonus Point :
if you access values in the same scopes don't use `find()` method in each statement.

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

then

```
$user->hair_color_name;
$user->nationality_name;
```